# Update permalink of a parent page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I want to update the permalink of a parent page in WordPress so that all its child pages' URLs also get updated.  For example: right now I've a Parent page with name "IT Courses" and it has several child pages.

The permalink for the child pages [appear like this](http://www.something.com/it-courses-2/childpage). I want to change the permalink for all child pages to `http://wwww.something.com/it-courses/childpage`.

I've my ads running on Google Adwords with the links, which I want to update to.

Comment: Stack Overflow translation: "urgent help appreciated" = "downvote my post ASAP plz!!!1".

Comment: To understand why, please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far? It's expected that you have researched your issue and tried to solve it yourself before posting. The fact that the slug has "-2" appended suggests that you already have a slug with that name, and WP doesn't allow you to have 2 slugs with the same name. That might help you do some research on your issue so you can give us some relevant information we can use to help. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)